# How To Access DOM-Elements with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a Navigation-Component holding 3 Sub-Components:

**NavigationHeader
NavigationList
NavigationBtn**

In the NaviationBtn-Element i have a Button on which i want to add the eventlistener: **onClick={btnClickHandler}**

This **Clickhandler** should get access to the **NavigationLists-DOM-Elements** and set the attribute: `display: hidden` attribute.

I've read, it's bad-practice to select any dom-elements in react with getElementsById/ClassName whatsoever and use **'useRef'** instead.

But I'm not sure on how to achieve that!

Thank You for any help!

Comment: Please provide some code to get the context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with state management.
Create a function inside your parent component, that changes a state to "true" and "false".

```
const [show, setshow] = useState(false);
const showFunction = () => {
  setshow(!show)
};
```

Give a reference to your Btn component (send as props). and call this function inside your button handler;

```
const btnClickHandler = () => {
  props.stateFunction()
};
```

And send this state to your other child component as a props.
and use this state insdie your html element as an attribute boolean.

```
display:`${props.show ? "none" : ""}`
```

hope its help...